# hot water coming from cold faucets in one building only,

Tags: plumbing, faucet

We have 5 buildings roughly with 18 - 21 units each. (a-e). the apartments have 2 boilers that heat up the complex. they are located in the same room next to building A.. building A is getting warm to hot water from there cold side of there fixtures (kitchen, bathroom and shower). we have changed all cartridges from the showers in the building, we have replaced all single handle fixtures to double handles in kitchen and bathroom sinks. warn to hot water is still coming out the cold side of that building (A). as of now i'm stumped why this is happening. any suggestions would help. thank.

Comment: Is cold water coming from the hot side of _every_ fixture? Is hot water in the places where only cold water should be (toilets, exterior faucet, etc.)?

Comment: Check the boiler room... seems like a main mixer valve has malfunctioned.

Comment: Who is "we" ?  If you haven't called in a licensed plumber yet, you should.   Question: is this a new problem or has it always been like this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, questions that are specific to large commercial properties aren't a good fit here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's specific to large commercial properties.

Comment: "... we have changed all cartridges from the showers in the building, we have replaced all single handle fixtures to double handles in kitchen and bathroom sinks...."  -- I don't see how this fits into the question.... Did the problem just start when you did this work, or was this work an attempt to fix it?